# Elastic Search URI /_cluster/nodes not accessible

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

My Elastic search instance has been booted up. 
I am able to access other uri's such as 
localhost:9200/_cluster/health and others.

But when I am accessing the elastic search through perl it is trying to access the uri localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes.

The error I am getting is No handler found for uri [/_cluster/nodes] and method [GET]

Comment: localhost:9200/_nodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_cluster/nodes` endpoint has been removed in [#4055](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4055), which is why your call returns an error. The change was released with elasticsearch 1.0.0.RC1. You can use the simplified `_nodes` endpoint instead now.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting:

> No handler found for uri [/_cluster/nodes] and method [GET]

means that the url you are hitting is incorrect. Not exactly certain what you are trying to do, but I suspect you are trying to hit one of these two REST apis:

```
http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats
http://localhost:9200/_nodes
```

This page in the Elasticsearch documentation list the cluster related REST api endpoints (includes the two above):

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html